# How can I edit this code so that it only affects the top menu and not the main menu on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using OceanWP theme to create my site.

I have two different menus on my homepage, I have a top menu and I also have a main menu. http://prntscr.com/pofn5r

I would like for the top menu to display different options for users who are logged in and users who are logged out.

I have used the following code which I placed in the functions.php file. I have also created two different menus for logged in and logged out users:

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
$args['menu'] = 'logged_in';
} else {
$args['menu'] = 'logged_out';
}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

It seems to work in terms of showing different menus for users which are logged in and users which are logged out but the problem is that it also changes the main menu as well as the top menu.

prntscr.com/podv5e

I wanted the main menu to remain the same and just have the top menu change depending on whether a user is logged in or out.

I was wondering if there was a way I could amend the code so that it only affects the top menu and not the main menu?

Comment: I had the same issue.
Heres how I fixed the problem - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69960937/17408003

Answer (score 0):

Check the the `theme_location` argument for matching the correct nav.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_nav_menu_args

Comment: Hi Jordan Cauley, thanks for this. I am just a little unsure what the theme location is? Where would I find that?

Comment: @Jas in the theme, where the nav is registered it will have a name of the specific nav area, you can also print_r the $args to see the different values display on the page. It’s hard to know more without looking at your theme code.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the free version of OceanWP and in functions.php you have this code

```
// Register navigation menus
register_nav_menus( array(
    'topbar_menu'     => esc_html__( 'Top Bar', 'oceanwp' ),
    'main_menu'       => esc_html__( 'Main', 'oceanwp' ),
    'footer_menu'     => esc_html__( 'Footer', 'oceanwp' ),
    'mobile_menu'     => esc_html__( 'Mobile (optional)', 'oceanwp' )
) );
```

So you would want to be targeting 'topbar_menu'

Comment: thank you very much for this:) I have tried adding topbar_menu to the code but it is still not working for me. I think I may not be using it correctly. I have added  if ( $args['theme_location'] === 'top-menu' ) { in front of my code, I was just wondering which part I would replace with 'topbar_menu'?