# Hide/Show menus when logged in/out on WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, navigation

My website is built with WordPress and I currently have 3 nav menus

1. The main menu - "Main"
2. A secondary top menu - "Player Logged-in"
3. Another secondary top menu - "Player Logged-out"

Ive added the script below to my functions.php

```
function my_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
    $args['menu'] = "Player Logged-in";
} else { 
    $args['menu'] = "Player Logged-out";
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```

It is working, the only problem is it replaces my "Main" menu with one of the secondary menus.
How would I go about it if I wanted the 2 secondary top menus to alternate if a user is logged in/out AND I wanted the "Main" menu to stay regardless of whether the user is logged in or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I came right with this problem.
I looked for the specific menu locations (top_navigation) for my theme (Avada) and used this

```
function wpc_wp_nav_menu_args( $args = '' ) {
if( is_user_logged_in()) { 
    if( 'top_navigation' == $args['theme_location'] ) { 
    //top_navigation is specific to Avada in my case
        $args['menu'] = 'Player Logged-in';
    }
} else { 
    if( 'top_navigation' == $args['theme_location'] ) { 
    //again, top_navigation is specific to Avada in my case
        $args['menu'] = 'Player Logged-out';
    }
} 
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'wpc_wp_nav_menu_args' );
```